# ImageView only showing last image in loop

Tags: java, opencv, javafx

Hello this what i'm doing is that i'm receiving images from client and displaying it in the loop .. data is correctly received but only last received image is shown when loop finishes..

this is not the main controller this is in thread. I don't know whats wrong as it's receiving data and it should update on every iteration....

Here is code:

```
@FXML  ImageView currentframe;
public void run()
{
        System.out.println("hi controller");  
        System.out.println("creating socket");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket=null; 
        try {
            serverSocket = new  DatagramSocket(1001);
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(threadclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("created socket");

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[50000]; 

        //byte[] sendData  = new byte[1024]; 
        //BufferedImage img = null;
        //Image image = null;

        int counter = 0;

        while(counter<20){
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
            try {  
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(threadclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //System.out.println("packetreceive");
            BufferedImage img = null;

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(receivePacket.getData()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(threadclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //System.out.println("packetreceive1");
            System.out.println("received packet length "+receivePacket.getLength());

            Image image= SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null); 

            Image tempImg = image;

            Platform.runLater(() -> currentframe.setImage(tempImg));


            /*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(threadclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }*/

            //currentframe.setImage(image);
            //threadclass t = new threadclass(currentframe, image);
            //t.start();

           //Platform.runLater(null);

            counter++;
            System.out.println("IMAGE SET ON FRAME...");
        }
        //System.out.println("ssdcd" );
        // currentframe.setImage(image);
        //System.out.println("last packet ");
}
```

here is how i'm starting thread in the controller:

```
@FXML
public void btn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
        threadclass t = new threadclass(currentframe);
        t.run();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not running this in a background thread. Show how you are starting the thread.

Comment: I'm using button event to start thread, i have added the code.

Comment: Umm, `t.run()`?

Comment: oops my bad it should be t.start() right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
t.run();
```

simply invokes the `run()` method on the current thread (which is probably the FX Application thread). To start a new thread, you need to call

```
t.start();
```

assuming `threadclass` (sic) is a subclass of `Thread`.